# How to stop Socket to send a lot of useless data when closed?

Tags: android, sockets, serversocket

I use these codes for communicating between devices. If i close or kill the client app, the server app gets thousands of useless data. The textView in the server side is full of this: `Client says: null`. If i close the client twice, the server stops with `StackOverFlowError`. How can i make the code to dont send this `null` values when the app stops? Or can i filter the server side to do nothing when getting this data? 
Client:

```
 public class Client extends Activity {

    private Socket socket;

    private static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.2.2";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      

        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            String str = et.getText().toString();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            out.println(str);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Server:

```
public class Server extends Activity {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    Handler updateConversationHandler;

    Thread serverThread = null;

    private TextView text;



    public static final int SERVERPORT = 1599;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

        updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

        this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        this.serverThread.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    socket = serverSocket.accept();

                    CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                    new Thread(commThread).start();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

        private Socket clientSocket;

        private BufferedReader input;

        public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

            try {

                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {


            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    String read = input.readLine();

                    updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
        private String msg;

        public updateUIThread(String str) {
            this.msg = str;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    String read = input.readLine();

                    updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

The problem is here. You aren't checking the result of `readLine()` for null. If it returns null, the peer has closed the connection and you should do likewise, and exit this loop. You can probably get rid of the `isInterrupted()` test as well.

Also, if you get any `IOException` other that a read timeout when reading from a socket, the connection is dead and you must close the socket and exit your loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a delimiter character, to tell the Server your Client it's about to die. Add that character of code in onPause method of your Android Activity/Fragment. 
Then in your Server, just get the String or byte and compare it against your Delimiter String/Character and stop the Server listening for the Connection.

Comment: Unnecesary. The problem is that he isn't checking for *anything,* even EOS.